# How do I change the path of file from oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ubuntu-14.04, sqlplus

I have `ubuntu 14.04` and  `oracle  XE 11` 
if to execute a file sql from `Oracle` i do :

```
SQL > @ /........./Desktop/file.sql
```

how change the a path of  `oracle` , Means I create file in Desktop 
and i do :

```
SQL > @ file .sql
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. Are you asking how to move a file within the underlying file system or are you asking how to run a file on a relative path or are you asking something else?

Comment: **It has nothing to do with Oracle**. Just go to the directory and then execute it. It will look for the file in current directory. Else, set the `SQLPATH` variable as @AlexPoole suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `$SQLPATH` environment variable before running SQL*Plus. From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_two.htm#r11c1-t2):

> SQLPATH - Environment variable or Windows registry entry to specify the location of SQL scripts. SQL*Plus searches for SQL scripts, including login.sql, in the current directory and then in the directories specified by SQLPATH, and in the subdirectories of SQLPATH directories. SQLPATH is a colon separated list of directories. There is no default value set in UNIX installations.

So:

```
export SQLPATH=/........./Desktop
sqlplus
```

Alternatively, just `cd` to the Desktop directory before launching SQL*Plus, as it will look for scripts in the current directory first anyway.

Answer (score 1):

@alex poole for the win!

A small additional thought; just like the unix PATH variable, you can have several paths defined in the SQLPATH variable, so sqlplus can look in several locations to find the referenced script.